# c programming "Access violation writing location 0x00000000."

Tags: c

I'm working on a program which I need to get string from a user and do some manipulates on it.

The problem is when my program ends I am getting "Access violation writing location 0x00000000." error message.

This is my code

```
}
  //code
  char *s;
  s=gets();
  //code
}
```

After some reading I relized that using gets() may cause some problems so I changed char *s to s[20] just to check it out and it worked fine without any errors at the end of the program.

The thing is that I don't know the string size in advance, thus, I'm not allowed (academic ex) to create string line as -> s[HugeNumber] like s[1000].
So I have no other choice but using gets() function.

Any way to solve my problem?
Thanks in advance

PS
Also tried using malloc as

```
char *temp;
char *s;
temp = gets();
s= (char*)malloc((strlen(temp) +1)* sizeof(char));
```

Error still popup at the end.
As long as I have *something = gets(); my program will throw an error at the end.

Comment: There is no safe way to use gets(). Quoth Linux man page: "Never use this function."

Comment: Do not use `gets()`, use `fgets()`. And *if* you  still use `gets()` (in fact any function) it might be a good idea to read its documentation.

Comment: You are calling `gets` incorrectly. It takes a single parameter that points to the buffer to be written to. Also, `gets` is inherently dangerous and you should never use it.

Comment: Use `getline` instead of `gets`.

Comment: And which compiler does compile this?

Comment: In my manpage `gets()` takes a parameter. Why do you hide what you are passing here?
Look at the parameter that you pass to gets. Seems that you do not initialize s when you call `s=gets(s);`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are expecting gets to allocate an appropriately-sized string and return a pointer to it but that is not how it works. `gets` needs to receive the buffer as a parameter so you would still need to declare the array with a huge number. In fact, I am surprised that you managed to get your code to compile since you are passing the wrong number of arguments to gets.

```
char s[1000];
if (gets(s) == NULL) {
    // handle error
}
```

The return value of gets is the same pointer that you passed as a parameter to it. The only use of the return value is to check for errors, since gets will return NULL if it reached the end of file before reading any characters.

A function that works more similarly to what you want is [`getline`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html) in the GNU libc:

```
char *s;
size_t n=0;
getline(&s, &n, stdin);

printf("%s", s); // Use the string here

free(s); //Then free it when done.
```

Alternatively, you could do something similar using malloc and realloc inside a loop. Malloc a small buffer to start out then use fgets to read into that buffer. If the whole line fits inside the buffer you are done. If it didn't then you realloc the buffer to something larger (multiply its size by a constant factor each time) and continue reading from where you stopped.

Another approach is to give up on reading arbitrarily large lines. The simplest thing you can do in C is to set up a maximum limit for line length (say, 255 characters), use fgets to read up to that number of characters and then abort with an error if you are given a line that is longer than that. This way you stick to functions in the standard library and you keep your logic as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You have not allocated temp.
And 3 kinds of C you should avoid i.e.

```
void main() use int main() instead
fflush(stdin)
gets() use fgets() instead
```

Comment: You have not stated why OP should use your versions instead of his.  Also, your main answer to the question is far to limited and won't actually help him solve the problem.  Please keep this in mind for future answers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I typed it on my mobile phone. It's quite difficult for me to type so long.

Comment: But I shall improve anyway. :-)